# Why lights create this kind of concentric patterns?

Tags: visible-light, interference, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

Inspired by a youtube video, i was trying to do the double slit experiment at home using a single hair and saw the interference pattern.

[image]

Then i wondered what would happens with many hairs and when i shine the laser trough a bunch of them, these kind of patterns emerge.

[image]

[image]

Here you can see a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utJyBEfwugE

Sorry if the question is too generic, i'm not a physics student.

Comment: its just the picture you get from several, hairs in different directions. if you take the first picture turn it about 45° and add it to so original, you get the second, overlay some more turned pictures and you get the third

Comment: @trula ah i see, well i will try to make more rigorous experiments in the future, it was just for fun

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the exact geometry of the hairs.  Their relative orientation and spacing will uniquely specify what the light pattern will be. However, if you just show a light pattern it's not unique what the structure is that created it.

Comment: the first picture has the hair straight vertically. The third and the ones in the videos is just through my hair, taking a bunch of them and making them also straight with my fingers, but i guess the randomness of their position and curvature produces those patterns. My surprise is about the complete circles that appears (better shown in the video)

Comment: The circles are very bright, so one can not say exact circles. again in the video you have nut always circles and adding up some single pictures you easily get kind of a circle

Comment: @trula is there some link i can check for why the light hitting with some angle the hair produce those curved lines?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "curved lines"